# What is the recommended approach to flush dispatcher cache for shortened URLs?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, aem

I am using AEM 6.3.1.0. To achieve URL shortening I used [sling mappings](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/managing/using/seo-and-url-management.html) and it works fine. Now at apache, the cache is persisted with shortened paths as /en/home.html, /en/home/page1.html etc.

This disturbs flush agents as when /content/myapp/en/home is published, corresponding path is not found in apache and no flushing happens. This makes /en/home.html obsolete.

I am further reading ACS Commons has [an awesome tool](https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/dispatcher-flush-rules/index.html) that exactly caters this. 
Second [Adobe replies](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/HowToFlushMappedContent.html) to fix using Apache rewrite rules and persist cache in full complete path as AEM.

Have anyone tried both approaches and is there any recommendation? Is there any caveats persisting cache as full qualified path?

Edit: My dispatcher.any file was referred from [here](https://github.com/adfinis-sygroup/aem-docker/blob/master/aem-dispatcher/dispatcher.any) and /docroot looks like this:

```
/cache
  /docroot "/opt/apache2/cache"
  #/statfileslevel "3"
  #/allowAuthorized "1"
  #/serveStaleOnError "1"
```

I tried editing /docroot specific to path as '/opt/apache2/cache/content/myapp' and still files are not invalidated. 
Am I missing any basic configuration to invalidate the cache?

Comment: What is the document root path for your cached content? If you have /content/mysite, then, the shortened URL should not disturb the dispatcher flushing.

Comment: I have edited the question. I originally didnt have /content/mysite. Then I tried adding and doesnt work either.

Comment: You could use any of the solutions you referenced and it would work fine. If you want to control the path that get's flushed in a java service, take a look at my post here: https://blogs.perficient.com/adobe/2017/08/11/how-to-transform-replication-urls-in-aem/

Comment: I'd vote for keeping the content structure and cache structure same via re write rules. This solves the cache invalidation issue and makes things a lot simpler when you have multiple domains being powered by same AEM instance.

Comment: @SaravanaPrakash When you go to /content/myapp are the files being created? Also, use level 3 for dispatcher debugging log, and share the output when you activate an asset from the author. Thanks.

Comment: I think @SharathMadappa helped with recommendation. After changing rewrite rules jcr content structure is matched to cache structure. Additional I also tried solution of Ahmed Musallam and it also works as I didnt want to add ACS dependency just for 1 solution. Closing the ticket with rewrite rules win.